# Bind classes with AlpineJS but also include other classes?

Tags: alpine.js

I can bind a class like so:

```
 <div :class="active ? '' : 'hidden'>
```

But how can I also include standard classes on the element that are not overridden?

If I just do:

```
<div class="header" :class="active ? '' : 'hidden'>
```

That class is overwritten.

How can I add the `header` class?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="loading-screen " :class="{'' : isLoading, 'u-hide' : !isLoading}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alpine's [**Class Object Syntax**](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/bind#class-object-syntax).

```html
<div class="header" :class="{ 'hidden': !active }">
```

It appends all objects' keys to your class list whose value evaluates to true.
In your case `if (!active) === true` (i.e. active is `false`) add the class `hidden`.